# Sending duplicate to heaven with Java 8

Tags: java, programming-challenge, stream, lambda

Follow up to [Duplicate like a weapon, arrays like heaven](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/duplicate-like-a-weapon-arrays-like-heaven/79982#79982).

@rolfl suggested in chat that I try to complete this challenge again in a Java 8 friendly way. I took the opportunity to also employ the algorithm suggested in this brilliant [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/duplicate-like-a-weapon-arrays-like-heaven/79982#79982).

I'm not familiar with Java 8 features, but am definitely interested in using it more and finding the best ways to implement it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayAbsurdityJava8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(new File(args[0]).toPath())
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                .forEach(ArrayAbsurdityJava8::printDuplicate);
    }

    private static void printDuplicate(String line) {
        int length = Integer.parseInt(line.split(";")[0]);
        int total = Arrays.stream(line.split(";")[1].split(","))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .sum();

        System.out.println(total - (length - 1) * (length - 2) / 2);
    }
}
```

This ended up shorter than I expected. Is this best? I was thinking of doing it my way as well, but the `boolean` comparison requires a `for` loop (am I wrong?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the way you have solved this, and cannot think of any serious criticisms. The most significant thing I can think of is the double-duty method `printDuplicate`. I would prefer that method to be just `findDuplicate` and then print the value outside the function. That makes the function more reusable.

Other trivials are:

> ```
> new File(args[0]).toPath()
> ```

should be:

```
Paths.get(args[0])
```

Finally, I would expect the 'expected' value to be a simpler algorithm. The code:

```
(length - 1) * (length - 2) / 2
```

is just messy, and hard to understand.

The reasons it is like that are because of two factors:

1. You expect the sum to be based on the number of values less 1 for the duplicate.
2. the forumla is designed for a 1-based start point, not a 0-based one.

As a result, the input value: `5;3,2,1,0,1` should have the expected-value calculated from 4 values, not 5, and indexed from 0, not 1. I would recode the formula to be:

```
(values - 1) * (values) / 2
```

where `values` is:

```
Integer.parseInt(....) - 1;
```

Incorporating [@mjolka's good suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/80120/31503) and simplifying the functions, you can end up with improved code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .mapToInt(s -> findDuplicate(s))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static int findDuplicate(String line) {
    String[] parts = line.split(";");

    // expect is based on 1-fewer values than are supplied (no duplicate)
    int expect = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) - 1;

    int total = Arrays.stream(parts[1].split(","))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();

    return total - ((expect - 1) * (expect)) / 2;
}
```

As a side note, the total can be computed easily in a parallel stream, instead of a stream. This would, in theory, improve performance for large arrays of data in systems with multiple cores:

```
    int total = Arrays.parallelStream(parts[1].split(","))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
```

Answer (score 6):

`line.split(";")` is being called twice, so you can assign it to a variable to remove one of the calls.

Since we know there's only one `;` per line, we can use `indexOf` to find it, and `substring` to extract the relevant parts of the string. This may be a little bit faster than calling `split(";")`.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 Streams you can also [using arrays or collections](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/80411/65056) to get an algorithm that runs with constant memory, no matter how long your lines are. The complexity would be O(1) memory and O(n) time, where n is the line length - if you have m lines, you'll have O(n*m). The time complexity if your algorithm is the same, but it reads the full line into memory, so takes O(n) memory.

```
public class FindDuplicates8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        input.useDelimiter("[;,]|\r?\n");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int n = input.nextInt();
            long sum = Stream.generate(() -> input.nextInt())
                    .limit(n)
                    .mapToLong(x -> x.longValue())
                    .sum();
            System.out.println(sum - (n - 2) * (n - 1) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm heavily relying on the format of the input being correct - I don't distinguish between ';' and ',' and ignore line breaks. That's probably not be what you want in a real program - I just want to demonstrate the algorithmic possibilities.