# Optimization of a "Sieve of Eratosthenes" in Java

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have created a simple Pseudo "Sieve of Eratosthenes," for a class in Java. I am looking for the most optimized option, or at least an option that is more optimized than current. If there is any other advice that you have to offer, I would be more than happy to hear that as well.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SieveOfErantosthenes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testerIndex = 0, numbersOnLine = 0;
        Vector<Integer> primes = new Vector<Integer>(1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            primes.add(i + 1);
        }
        primes.remove(0);
        while ((primes.get(testerIndex)) < 500) {
            for (int i = testerIndex + 1; i < 999; i++) {
                if (primes.get(i) % primes.get(testerIndex) == 0
                        && primes.get(i) != 0) {
                    primes.set(i, 0);
                }

            }
            do {
                testerIndex++;
            } while (primes.get(testerIndex) == 0);
        }
        while (primes.contains(0)) {
            primes.remove((Integer) 0);
        }
        testerIndex = 0;
        while(testerIndex < primes.size()){
            for(; numbersOnLine < 15 && testerIndex < primes.size(); testerIndex++, numbersOnLine++){
                System.out.print(primes.get(testerIndex) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            numbersOnLine = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that [usage of java.util.Vector is discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792134/a-colleague-said-dont-use-java-util-vector-anymore-why-not). It is an older class that has essentially been practically replaced.

Comment: @brcolow what should I use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, a few notes:

Your for loop strikes one as odd.

> ```
>  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
>                 primes.add(i + 1);
>             }
> ```

Why not start iteration at 1 and have your conditional be  `<= 1000`, and you could just call `primes.add(i)` Note that this is just an example to be equivalent to yours, just removing unnecessary bloat, it actually makes the most sense to start with 2 for a sieve, since it's the first prime. These changes would more clearly communicate your intention.

Courtesy of [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79705/premium-palindromic-primes/79711#79711) I learned that a sieve is best implemented through a simple boolean array.

> ```
>   boolean[] sieve = new boolean[1000];
>     Arrays.fill(sieve, true);
>
>  for (int prime = 2; prime < sieve.length; prime++) {
>         if (sieve[prime]) {
>             // this is a prime number
>           for (int notPrime = prime * 2; notPrime < sieve.length; notPrime += prime) {
>               sieve[notPrime] = false;
>           }
>         }
>     }
> ```

As this answer notes there may be ways to improve it, but I like this implementation for being light on memory (booleans are 1 bit) and the performance and convenience of simply using the indexes as the prime or not prime values.

**Edit**: Although booleans actually take up 1 bit in memory, the actual number of bits allocated is JVM dependent and typically a byte is reserved for each boolean used. Although the performance would be intangible using a [Bitset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) would be the target route to achieve 1 bit per boolean.

*If any of this was useful, please give the linked answer up-vote priority.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with Legato, up to a point.  Certainly, it seems to make more sense to use a Bitset to store the information.  This will mean that the Prime test will actually be running against the INDEX of the bits, not the VALUE of the bits, which, of course will all ways be 0 or 1.

However, representing 2 at Bitset index 0 and proceeding from there is a little 'iffy' in my opinion.  An explanation for that statement is in order.

I actually wrote a fairly small Java program to use a Bitset in generating a list of primes.  When I finished, I started looking at ways to 'optimize' the code.  Yes, I tinker with code (God help me).

Anyway, one of the 'optimizations' I implemented was using the first bitset value (index 0) to represent the number 2.  I THEN realized that, heck, I don't even have to represent 2 in the Bitset, at all as it is VERY well known that 2 is the smallest prime and the ONLY even prime.  This meant I could assign the value at index 0 to represent the 'primeness' of 3 with each successive index value representing the primeness of the NEXT odd number.  This would allow me to test for about twice as many primes using the original Bitset.

Does this sound complicated?  Well, it was complicated for ME, but your mileage may vary.  It also wasn't a lot of fun to implement.  And, at the end, I didn't really get all that big an improvement in elapsed time over my original code.  I think I got it about twice as fast, but that's all.  And the price for the speedup was code that in my opinion was harder to read and I knew I would be hard pressed to maintain the optimized code at any later date.

I'm not saying you SHOULDN'T consider some of these optimations, but what I WOULD suggest is that you should first implement your code using VERY FEW, if any, optimizations.  Check that code very carefully to make sure that it does, indeed, give you the results you're looking for.  Only THEN should you start down the 'optimization' path.

After all, how can you say you've 'optimized' the code if you don't know how long the unoptimized solution takes?  You might be pleasantly surprised at how efficient your first code really is.  Also, the unoptimized solution will serve as a 'test base' for the rest of the versions you come up with.

I wish you well with this and your future endeavors.